# When to include which TCP options into the segment

Tags: tcp, specifications, network-protocols

Cheers!

I'm working on a custom TCP implementation for a specific usecase, and the hope is that it should be able to chat with the wider world. I'm currently a little confused when it comes to TCP options (max segment, window scaling, sack, timestamp) though. Specifically, how often and when does any given TCP implementation expect those options?

My brain tells me that during the handshake you're expected to include practically everything: Max segment, Window scaling, timestamp, and SACK permitted, but what happens after that? Is my implementation expected to keep including all of those in every future segment I send, or can I omit some or all? And if I do omit some, are there situations where I should bring them back?

I've tried to read relevant RFCs, but I've failed to find any conclusive answers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could always use e.g. WireShark to look at some existing network stacks to see what they do?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do have a wireshark dump I've been looking at, but that hasn't given me the confidence I'd like, cause I haven't spotted all the cases I'd like to know about. Based on the file I have, it appears that after the handshake the option section can be dropped, but I would still like a confirmation and have some idea as to when I can (or should) bring it back.